# Ruby equivalent of PHP’s mcrypt_encrypt() function

Tags: ruby, encryption

Is there a Ruby equivalent of PHP’s `mcrypt_encrypt()` function?

Answer (score 1):

check the Crypt gem - http://crypt.rubyforge.org/index.html

Comment: Thank you for answering!
If I write the following code

 mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $raw, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
How to write in ruby?

Comment: http://crypt.rubyforge.org/rijndael.html. CBC is the default (and only mode - http://crypt.rubyforge.org/cbc.html). Not sure about IV though, you might want to raise a question in the forum or tracker @ http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=899